# data in not insert in database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I'm new to C# and I was trying to insert data into database with this code.

Please help me how can I fix this error which occurs on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` when i try to insert the data and click to submit:

> ExecutenonQueryexception cant handle by the system.data.dll

How can I solve this error?

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\adityaDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**asp code**..

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AGD.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ConsumerRegistration.aspx.cs" Inherits="Aditya_Gas_Distributor.ConsumerRegistration" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <center>
                <br />
                <form runat="server">
                        <table style="border: ridge solid #5D7B9D; background-color: Window; width: 665px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" align="center" style="background-color: #C1312F">
                                    <b style="color: White">Gas Connection Registration Form </b>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>FirstName<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                                <td colspan="3" rowspan="4">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="133px"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>MiddleName<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>LastName<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td>Gender<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList  runat="server" ID="ddl1">
                                        <asp:ListItem>--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>DOB<samp style="color:red">*</samp>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>




                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                                <td>Connection Type<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td valign="middle" align="left">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlConnection" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="107px">
                                        <asp:ListItem>--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Domestic</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Commercial</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>State Name<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" Width="157px">
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True">--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Andaman and Nicobar Islands</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Andhra Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Arunachal Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Assam</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Bihar</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Chandigarh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Chattisgarh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Dadra and Nagar Haveli</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Daman and Diu</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Delhi</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Goa</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Gujarat</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Haryana</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Himachal Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Jammu and Kashmir</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Jharkhand</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Karnataka</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Kerala</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Lakshadweep</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Madhya Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Maharashtra</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Manipur</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Meghalaya</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Mizoram</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Nagaland</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Orissa</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Pondicherry</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Punjab</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Rajasthan</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Sikkim</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Tamil Nadu</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Tripura</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Uttarakhand</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Uttaranchal</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>Uttar Pradesh</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem>West Bengal</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDistrict" runat="server" Text="District Name"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left"><samp style="color:red">*</samp>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldistrict" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>aa</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server" Text="City Name"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td><samp style="color:red">*</samp>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_city" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>aa</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblAgency" runat="server" Text="Agency Name"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <samp style="color:red">*</samp>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_agency" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem>aa</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email Id<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                                <td>PhoneNo<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                                <td>


                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>User Name<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td>

                                </td>
                                <td rowspan="2">Address<samp style="color:red">*</samp>
                                </td>
                                <td rowspan="2" align="left">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" Height="80px"
                                        Width="176px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                <td rowspan="2">

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="height: 62px">Password<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td style="height: 62px">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                                <td style="height: 62px">

                                    <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToCompare="txtPassword" ControlToValidate="cnfrmpass" ErrorMessage="CompareValidator" ForeColor="#CC3300">Password &amp; Confirm Password Must be Same</asp:CompareValidator>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Confirm Password<samp style="color:red">*</samp></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="cnfrmpass" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                                    &nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="cancle" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6" style="background-color: #C1312F"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
            </center>
        </div>
    </asp:Content>
```

C# code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace Aditya_Gas_Distributor
{
    public partial class ConsumerRegistration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
           // SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con.Open();
            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["adityaDB"].ConnectionString;

                Label1.Text = "Connected";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_UserRegistration (UserName, Password, FirstName, MName, LastName, Gender, DOB, State, District, City, ConnectionType, AgencyName, Address, PhoneNo, Email, Image, FileName)" +
                      "VALUES(@UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @MName, @LastName, @Gender, @DOB, @State, @District, @City, @ConnectionType, @AgencyName, @Address, @PhoneNo, @Email, @Image, @FileName)", con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName",txtUserName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtMName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddl1.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtDOB.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddlstate.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@District", ddldistrict.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", ddl_city.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectionType", ddlConnection.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgencyName", ddl_agency.SelectedItem.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", txtPhone.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",Image1.ImageUrl);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileUp.PostedFile.FileName);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: For SqlCommand to execute you need an open Sql Connection. Opening a connection on page load on a local variables does not help.

Comment: Re: _"ExecutenonQueryexception cant handle by the system.data.dll"_ Please cite the original exception message; don't paraphrase it (you're making it more vague that way).

Answer (score 2):

For `SqlCommand` to execute you need an open `SqlConnection`. Opening a connection on page load on a local variables does not help.
Also, keeping an instance of SqlConnection and SqlCommand on the page level is probably not the best idea. Your button click should have it's own SqlConnection, and since it's an IDisposable it should be used inside a using statement:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "Connected";

    using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_UserRegistration (UserName, Password, FirstName, MName, LastName, Gender, DOB, State, District, City, ConnectionType, AgencyName, Address, PhoneNo, Email, Image, FileName)" +
          "VALUES(@UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @MName, @LastName, @Gender, @DOB, @State, @District, @City, @ConnectionType, @AgencyName, @Address, @PhoneNo, @Email, @Image, @FileName)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtMName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddl1.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", txtDOB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", ddlstate.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@District", ddldistrict.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", ddl_city.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConnectionType", ddlConnection.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgencyName", ddl_agency.SelectedItem.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNo", txtPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", Image1.ImageUrl);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileUp.PostedFile.FileName);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Remove the page level `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`, and remove the opening of the local `SqlConnection` in the `Page_Load`.

Comment: okay! but where can i opening sql connection? and also why page level is not best idea? give me in detail description.

Comment: Please read the code in the answer. It has a local variable for SqlConnection. Keeping a connection to the database is expensive in terms of reasourses, so you want it open only when it's actually needed. Using any instance that implements IDisposable on the page (or class) level is almost always a bad idea. IDisposable objects should be disposed as soon as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your object `con` is wrong in below line.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_UserRegistration (UserName, Password, FirstName, MName, LastName, Gender, DOB, State, District, City, ConnectionType, AgencyName, Address, PhoneNo, Email, Image, FileName)" +
                      "VALUES(@UserName, @Password, @FirstName, @MName, @LastName, @Gender, @DOB, @State, @District, @City, @ConnectionType, @AgencyName, @Address, @PhoneNo, @Email, @Image, @FileName)", con);
```

be sure to set it before creating command object.

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["adityaDB"].ConnectionString;
```